# How to analytic why Xamarin. Form deploy to Android Emulator is very slow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]I have this weird situation that after I build xamarin.form and try to deploy to android emulator. Most of the time works fine, only few times the code will stack on the following line. Do you know why this is happening? Or How to troubleshooting this?

*1>C:\Users{MyWindowsUserFolder}\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK\build-tools\25.0.1\zipalign.exe 4 "C:{Xamarin.Form.Folder}{MyAndroidApp}\bin\Debug\com.companyname.myApp-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\com.companyname.myApp-Signed.apk"*

So far, the only work around and most of the time is working is.

- Clean Solution
- Build Solution
- Deploy to Android Emulator

It's just happening once a while, it quite annoying behavior.

1. Emulator setup on my windows.

Comment: How about use https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/ this too is faster.

Comment: It says "Please note that the Xamarin Android Player is now discontinued. ", they don't support it anymore.

Comment: which emulator are you using? have you installed intel HAXM? Maybe try down- / upgrading the used build-tools (currently you seem to be using 25.0.1). Most recent version is 25.0.3

Comment: add screen of the emulator, yes HAXM is installed. it's weird just sometime happening.